# Pointwise mass released in arc of circunference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Pretty simple to describe problem: we have a 2 dimensional homogeneous hemi-circle with total mass $M$ standing on a line. And we release a point wise particle of mass $m$ in the top left corner.
 [image: problem]

I'm having trouble in describing the movement of the system and I want someone to try it. I'm gonna describe what I did in this problem:

First I tried Euler-Lagrange equation with the angle between the line connecting the particle with the center of the circle and the vertical line and the angle between the vertical and the perpendicular bisector bettwen the corners of the circle (the "vertical" axis of symetry of it) as generalized coordinates. But I think I messed up the kinematics of it: I assumed the center of circle had same velocity as the center of mass of it which it don't: the center of mass of the hemi-circle goes up and down while the geometric center stays at constant height. So my big struggle is to describe velocity of the geometric center of the circle in terms of velocity of the other objects.

**EDIT**
I think I got it. Here are the final equations:

$\frac{g\cos(\phi)}{R}=\ddot{\phi} + \ddot\theta\cos(\phi)-\dot\theta\dot\phi\sin(\theta)$

$(\frac gR - \dot{\theta^2})\sin(\theta) = \ddot\theta(1+\frac{\pi m}{2M} - 2\cos(\theta))+\frac{\pi m}{2M}(\ddot\phi\cos(\phi)-\dot{\phi^2}\sin(\phi))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notations (bold letters are vectors):

- $\Omega$ is the centre of the hemisphere
- $R$ is the radius of the hemisphere
- $P$ is its point of contact on the ground
- $M$ mass rolling inside the hemisphere
- $\newcommand{\v}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\v{i}$ is a horizontal unit vector
- $\v{j}$ is a vertical unit vector
- $\v{k}$ to complete an orthonormal basis

First, the angular velocity of the hemisphere is $\dot{\theta}\v{k}$.

Then the velocity of $M$ is

$$\v{v}(M) = \v{v}(\Omega) + R\dot{\phi}(\cos\phi \v{i} + \sin\phi \v{j})$$

Then since I assume that the hemisphere is rolling without sliding on the ground,

$$\newcommand{\vv}[2]{\overrightarrow{#1#2}}\v{0} = \v{v}(P) = \v{v}(\Omega) + \dot{\theta}\v{k} \times \vv{\Omega}{P}$$

So

$$\v{v}(\Omega)=R\dot{\theta}\v{i}$$

I think that's all you need…

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot point $P$ had to have $0$ velocity

Comment: You're welcome: I happened to have given that exercise to my students eons ago and I am a compulsory collector ;-)